# How do I update a column that is set with the UNIQUE identifier?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, asyncpg

I recently fixed a bug that caused more bug in our database.

Basically, I didnt catch an extra condition in an if statement that caused the whole array index to be shifted by 1 and inserting all these wrong values into the database.

I have fixed the bug again, and am trying to update our current database to reflect the correct values.

DB Scheme looks like this -

post_id (primary key)
author_name TEXT
content TEXT
post_date DATE
metadata TEXT
UNIQUE(author_name, content)

When trying to do this update query in python using asyncpg

```
returned_data = dict(SELECT post_id, post_date from TABLE WHERE post_date = null AND metadata LIKE '%A unique identifer%')

returned_post_id = returned_data["post_id"]
```

```
"UPDATE TABLE SET author_name = $1, content = $2, post_date = $3 WHERE post_id = $4", name, content, date, returned_post_id
```

Upon running it, the code would spit out errors left and right stating that

"DUPLICATE key values violates unique constraint 'tablename_author_name_content_key'"

I tried to bypass this by deleting the whole row of post_id itself and reinserting it using

```
"DELETE FROM table where post_id = $1", returned_post_id
```

```
"INSERT INTO table (post_id, author_name, content, post_date, metadata) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)", returned_post_id, name, content, date, metadata
```

Although the second method works, but it feels wrong.. Deleting a primary key and reinserting it? Seems bad practice to me.. If anyone could enlighten me, i would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance

Comment: Run this by a higher-up as this isn't safe but the simplest option would be to remove the unique constraint temporarily, run your query and then add the constraint back.

Comment: You could define your constraint as `deferrable`. But I have to say that I find a unique constraint that includes a column named `content` a bit strange. And it will fail miserably when the content exceeds 2k even if it's not a duplicate

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi! I will try this out first thing in the office tomorrow! Thank you :) And btw, why is that so? What do you mean by when content exceeds 2k?

Comment: @SeanAnglim thanks for the response! Unfortunately, that wont be possible as this is a bot that crawls for posts every few hour..

Comment: Perfect example of why when fixing a bug you should **always** recreate the bug in a non production environment and fully **text the fix**.